# Update Div attribute with value from ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I am trying to pick values from the object and assign it to the div attribute (d.time) in my Angular8 HTML code, but the application fails to load when I try to access {{d.time}}

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let d of data;" date-is="{{d.time}}">
        <span>{{d.name}}</span>
        <br/>
        <span>{{d.vaue}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: use `[attr.date-is]="d.time">`  (And be sure that data has property "time")

Comment: can you share with us the error message or share more code ?

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks that worked.